# Wrong oil in trans

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, silverado

I have a 2013 Silverado 2500 with 150000 miles, about 5 miles after an oil change I noticed two hard shifts.

The next day I drove 1/2 mile, the trans slipped and is now disabled.

I had mechanic look at it and suggested it might be engine oil in the transmission. They suggested I drain the  transmission fluid  and change filter.  Less than 10 miles  since oil changed mechanics said that the oil looked brown not red, which is consistent with transmission fluid. They suggested it may be engine oil.

What is your opinion ?  Is there a recourse?

Comment: Is there recourse as far as what? Are you asking a legal question, or a remedial question?

Comment: Wow, who put the hammer vote on this question? This isn't a bad question, just needs some details.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 they asked for opinion?

Comment: @Moab - Which leads me to believe this question is opinion bait and should probably therefore be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Brown fluid is common in higher mileage automatic transmissions, especially if they do not get regular fluid changes.

Red ATF turns brown when it is worn out and the clutches in the transmission start slipping, creating friction and burning the fluid, turning it from red to brown.

I don't think it is anyone's fault, its just time for a transmission rebuild.

Comment: I suspect the smell would be a better indicator in this instance? Transmission fluid has a stank even when fresh that I've never smelled in any motor oil ever.

Comment: When it comes to automatic tranny fluid Brown is burnt, I don't have to smell it. I don't have to step in dog poop to know what it is either. :-)